# How can I find the Fourier series from discrete data?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I would like to define the function with Fourier series when I just have discrette data. (I don't have a specific function).

I can draw the graph using the data, but I don't have a idea how can I get this function. The plot is a periodic.

I want to obtain a function that will work like a Fourier series expansion. How can I define such a function?

Graph
[image]

Horizontal-axis is Time. Vertical-axis is Space.

Answer (score 5):

Use Fourier[]. It calculates the FFT of the data. Then you can change the magnitude and phase information into a sum of sinusoids. See the answer to this question:
[How to approximate a given WAV file with trigonometric series?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22095/how-to-approximate-a-given-wav-file-with-trigonometric-series/22096#22096) for details on how to do it.